# Restrict access from aws workspace to specific domains

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, firewall

I have created an AWS workspace for a developer and would like to allow access only to certain sites. Eg: google.com, npmjs.com, stackoverflow.com, etc. AWS has security groups that I can use to prevent access to/from certain IPs. However, obviously the domain's IP keep changing and I cannot use IP address restriction. What are the possibilities to allow access based on domain names?

One option that I could think of is setting up a proxy, but where does the proxy reside, secondly, in cases like npm the package information is downloaed from npmjs.com but the actual package could be pulled from github, how do I manage it?

Comment: So every time the developer needs to access a random forum thread or piece of obscure documentation that might solve their issue, they're going to have to send you an email and wait a few hours for you to put that site in their whitelist? Hope you're paying them for all the unproductive time you'll be generating.

Comment: @ceejayoz Not exactly, am providing them a laptop, where they can seemlessly use internet or browse or refer any document. See, I have clearly mentioned that this is an AWS workspace, they will be accessing from their laptop or Desktop. They can also browse any sites or refer any documentation from their machine, just not from the workspace.

Comment: @ceejayoz Why would you assume? the dev am asking to develop is not even an employee but a contractor. I am from a place where people do not consider code as an IP. I donot want to provide them a workspace where they upload the entire source code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest/cheapest solution would be to implement a SQUID proxy server, which allows wildcard domains too.
Implemented in the same AWS account (the proxy could be in another VPC, u just need to create the Security Groups and needed routing.

easy peasy